# How to load FXML with values from Preferences in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-2

I'm using what seems to be a typical JavaFX start() method when loading from an FXML file:

```
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    this.stage = stage;
    Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.<AnchorPane>load(getClass().getResource("layout.fxml")));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

I have some variables that correspond to controls, like:

```
    @FXML private TextField userName;
```

I would like to initialize userName to a value from the Preferences, as in:

```
    prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    userName.setText(prefs.get("userName", userName.getText()));
```

But when can I call this?  If I do it before the *stage.show*(), *userName* hasn't yet been instantiated.

TIA

Comment: How are you getting the controller? Are you creating the Preferences object in controller class?

Comment: I'm setting the Controller in the FXML and yes, I'm creating the Preferences there.  See below for an answer to my question, and thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your Controller implement `Initializable` and put loading to `initialize()`:

```
public class Sample implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TextField userName;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
        userName.setText(prefs.get("userName", userName.getText()));
    }    
}
```

Also note that your can use `ResourceBundle` and put your defaults directly to `fxml` file. Just create `my.properties` file and use it during loading:

```
FXMLLoader.load(
    getClass().getResource("layout.fxml"),
    ResourceBundle.getBundle("my"));
```

then in your fxml you may use properties from `my.properties`:

```
<TextField fx:id="userName" text="%userName" />
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had actually just figured that part out after rummaging though some more of the JavaFX documentation, but the tip about referencing the settings in the FXML file sounds very useful. Now I need to figure out how to catch the close event and save the values back.  Can you help with that, too?

Comment: please, write another question for this with more details.